# When Scanner.nextLong() throws InputMismatchException from try block then how does the Scanner.next() get the same value in catch block?

Tags: java, try-catch, buffer, inputmismatchexception

when i run the following code in java:

```
import java.util.*;
class Solution{
    public static void main(String []argh)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        try{
            long x=sc.nextLong();
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(sc.next()+" can't be fitted anywhere.");
        }
       sc.close();
   }
```

}

and enter the input as "23333333333333333333333333333333333333333"
it gives the following output :

`23333333333333333333333333333333333333333 can't be fitted anywhere.`

When `sc.nextLong()` throws `InputMismatchException` then how does the `sc.next()` in the catch block get the exact same value entered for `sc.nextLong()` in try block? Should it not ask for the input from consoleenter code here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your question is not about data type and it's maximum value and rather about the `Scanner`. If so, The [Scanner API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) mentions this:

> When a scanner throws an InputMismatchException, the scanner will not
>   pass the token that caused the exception, so that it may be retrieved
>   or skipped via some other method.

The scanner can still process the available input from stream incase of `InputMismatchException`

Comment: Yes this is what i wanted to know. Thank a lot :)

Comment: @cnova Sure. Mark the appropriate answer that suits you.

Answer (score 3):

Maximum value of long is `9223372036854775807`, your number is bigger than that. Try using `BigInteger`. `next()` takes the number as a *String*, so it can accept anything. Note that `next()` gets that value because that value is still present in the stream.

Comment: You can also add in the answer a quick reference link to the sizes of `primitive types` - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_datatypes.htm - as the answer is descriptive enough and should be accepted :)

Comment: Okay. So when `nextLong()` is executed, since the value is not assigned to `x` due to the `InputMismatchException`, it remains in the Stream, waiting to be consumed?

Comment: @cnova - Yes. What you can do is read it (into a String) and then ignore it. Then ask for next input

Comment: @TheLostMind - Okay. Thanks for the prompt answer :)